# Yii2 и проблема с ratchet

Tags: yii2, websocket, ratchet

Вообщем пишу чат сокетах, точнее пытаюсь это сделать для сокетов использую ratchet. И проблема в том, что при отправки сообщения ничего не происходит, скорее всего не срабатывает метод onMessage на стороне сокета.
Вот код js:

```
let websocketServerLocation = 'ws://localhost:9095/web-chat'; //название экшена должен совпадать с route в запускаемом через консоль экшене

let chat = null;
function socketStart(websocketServerLocation) {
    chat = new WebSocket(websocketServerLocation);

    chat.onmessage = function(e) {
        let response = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(response);
    };

    chat.onerror = function(e) {
        console.warn('Возникла ошибка');
        chat.close();
    };

    chat.onclose = function() {
        console.warn('Попытка подключения...');

        setTimeout(function() {
            socketStart(websocketServerLocation)
        }, 5000);
    };

    chat.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log('Вы онлайн');
    };

    $('.new-message-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let text = $('#textMessage').val();
        let only = 0;

        if ($('#onlyForAdmin').prop('checked') === true) {
            only = 1;
        }
        //
        $('#textMessage').val();
        $('#onlyForAdmin').prop('checked', false);

        let message = { id: chat_id, guid: chatGuid, web_id: webinarID, name: currentName, type: 0, only: only,
            time: new Date(), text: text };
        console.log(message);

        if (chat.readyState === chat.OPEN) {
            // Если соедение не открыто
            chat.send(message);
            addMessage(message);
        } else {
            console.warn('WS NOT CONNECTED');
        }
    });
}
```

Запуск данной функции идёт ниже в коде, но т.к. он слишком большой весь прикладывать не буду.
Вот код сокета:

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {

protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new SplObjectStorage();
}

public function onOpen (ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // Сохраните новое соединение для отправки сообщений позже
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New connection: " . $conn->resourceId . "\n";
}

public function onMessage (ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    Yii::info($from);

    $current_client = $this->findConnection($from);

    Yii::info($current_client);

    $request = json_decode($msg, true);
    $result = null;

    Yii::info($request);

    if (!empty($request['text']) && $message = trim($request['text'])) {
        // Здесь можно сохранять сообщения в БД
        $saved_message = Dialogs::saveMessage($request['id'], $request['guid'], $request['web_id'],
            $request['name'], $request['type'], $request['only'], $request['time'], $message);

        $result = $saved_message;

        if ($result !== null) {
            foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
//                    if ($from != $client) {
                    $client->send(json_encode([
                        'from' => $current_client->name,
                        'date' => date( 'H:i', $result->created_at ),
                        'message' => $message,
                    ]));
//                    }
            }
        } else {
            // Выводит сообщение если при сохранении возникли ошибки
            $result = $saved_message;
        }
    }

    $from->send(json_encode($result));
}

public function onClose (ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // Соединение закрыто, удалите его, так как мы больше не можем отправлять ему сообщения.
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    echo "Connection " . $conn->resourceId . " has disconnected\n";
}

public function onError (ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "Произошла ошибка: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";

    $conn->close();
}

public function findConnection( ConnectionInterface $conn ) {
    // Ищем пользователя, который написал
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($client->connection === $conn) {
            return $client;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Как видете я пытаюсь логировать некоторые данные, но они не появляють в логах.
Код вызова сокета:

```
public function actionStart() {
    $app = new RatchetApp('localhost', 9095);
//        $app = new App('localhost', 9095);
    $app->route('/web-chat', new Chat(), ['*']);
    $app->run();
}
```

Кстати класс `RatchetApp` создан чтобы обойти ошибку с xDebug.
Вот его код:

```
class RatchetApp extends App {
/**
 * RatchetApp constructor.
 * @param string $httpHost
 * @param int $port
 * @param string $address
 * @param LoopInterface $loop
 */
public function __construct(string $httpHost = 'localhost', int $port = 8080, string $address = '127.0.0.1',
    LoopInterface $loop = null) {
        @parent::__construct($httpHost, $port, $address, $loop);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё нашел в чем проблема оказывается всё просто надо просто перед отправкой сообщения на сервер завернуть его в json, вот так:

```
if (chat.readyState === chat.OPEN) {
        // Если соедение не открыто
        chat.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        addMessage(message);
    } else {
        console.warn('WS NOT CONNECTED');
    }
}
```